# How to set focus on dynamically generated textbox using JavaScript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a project in which I generate cells of a row dynamically. Making it more clear, in my scene I have 8-9 cells in a row. 1st and 2nd cells are buttons and after that are textboxes. Now there are `5 rows` automatically added on page load. When user fills data in this 5 rows, and he/she reaches at last row, after tabbing at last cell of last row, new 5 rows are generated.

I have done this using JavaScript. Now when I add this new 5 rows, focus can not be achieved on `first textbox (3rd cell)` of newly generated row. How to set focus on textbox of newly generated rows?

My code for rows:

```
function onRowDoubleClick_Add_Row(id, rowNo)
        {
            var New_RowNo = (parseInt(rowNo) + parseInt(1));
            var table = document.getElementById('<%= tblItem.ClientID %>');
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            row.setAttribute("class", "gridRow");

            // Delete
            var cell11 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell11.setAttribute("style", "width:20px;");
            var C11_element2 = document.createElement("input");
            var C11_EID = "MainContent_Image" + New_RowNo + "_" + New_RowNo + "_A_" + New_RowNo;  //"MainContent_Image10_A_10"
            var C11_EName = "ctl00$MainContent$Image" + New_RowNo + "_" + New_RowNo + "_A_" + New_RowNo;   //"ctl00$MainContent$Image10_A_10"
            C11_element2.type = "image";
            C11_element2.setAttribute("src", "Images/collapse.gif");
            C11_element2.setAttribute("title", "Delete");
            C11_element2.setAttribute("id", C11_EID.toString());
            var click = "return window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item');";
            C11_element2.setAttribute("Click", click);
            C11_element2.setAttribute("name", C11_EName);
            //var blur = "onRowDoubleClick_Add_Row('Image" + New_RowNo + "_A_" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "');";
            //C11_element2.setAttribute("onblur", blur);
            var Check_Delete = "Check_Delete('Image" + New_RowNo + "_A_" + New_RowNo + "');";
            //C11_element2.setAttribute("onmousedown", Check_Delete);
            cell11.appendChild(C11_element2);

            // Iten Number
            var cell1_1 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1_1.setAttribute("style", "width:25px;padding-right:5px;");
            var C1_element1_1 = document.createElement("input");
            C1_element1_1.type = "text";
            C1_element1_1.setAttribute("style", "width:100%;");
            C1_element1_1.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_txtItem" + New_RowNo);
            var blur = "getItemNoValue('txtItem" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_');";
            C1_element1_1.setAttribute("onblur", blur);
            C1_element1_1.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$txtItem" + New_RowNo);
            cell1_1.appendChild(C1_element1_1);

.

.

.

.

// Notes
            var cell10 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell10.setAttribute("style", "width:120px; padding-right: 5px;");
            // Added by Shiv on 12-02-2013 To Set editor on main grid
            var C10_element2 = document.createElement("textarea");
            C10_element2.type = "text";
            C10_element2.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height:30px;visibility: visible;");
            C10_element2.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_txtNote_New" + New_RowNo);
            C10_element2.setAttribute("class", "setFCkeditor");
            C10_element2.setAttribute("TextMode", "MultiLine");
            var blur = "NoteChange('txtNote" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_');";
            C10_element2.setAttribute("onblur", blur);
            C10_element2.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$txtNote" + New_RowNo);
            cell10.appendChild(C10_element2);

            //Qty
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(5);
            cell4.setAttribute("style", "min-width:10px; padding-right: 5px;");
            var C4_element2 = document.createElement("input");
            C4_element2.type = "text";
            C4_element2.setAttribute("style", "width:95%;");
            C4_element2.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_txtQty" + New_RowNo);
            var blur = "OrderQtyChange('txtQty" + New_RowNo + "',' " + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_');";
            C4_element2.setAttribute("onblur", blur);
            C4_element2.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$txtQty" + New_RowNo);
            cell4.appendChild(C4_element2);
            var C4_exID = "MainContent_FilteredTextBoxExtender_txtQty" + New_RowNo;
            var C4_exPlant = "MainContent_txtQty" + New_RowNo;
            Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                $create(Sys.Extended.UI.FilteredTextBoxBehavior,
                {
                    "ValidChars": "1234567890.",
                    "id": C4_exID
                },
                null, null, $get(C4_exPlant));
            });

            //Hour
            var cellHour = row.insertCell(6);
            cellHour.setAttribute("style", "min-width:10px; padding-right: 5px;");
            var cellHour_element2 = document.createElement("input");
            cellHour_element2.type = "text";
            cellHour_element2.setAttribute("style", "width:95%;");
            cellHour_element2.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_txtHour" + New_RowNo);
            var blur = "OrderQtyChange('txtQty" + New_RowNo + "',' " + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_');";
            cellHour_element2.setAttribute("onblur", blur);
            cellHour_element2.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$txtHour" + New_RowNo);
            cellHour.appendChild(cellHour_element2);
            var cellHour_exID = "MainContent_FilteredTextBoxExtender_txtHour" + New_RowNo;
            var cellHour_exPlant = "MainContent_txtHour" + New_RowNo;
            Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                $create(Sys.Extended.UI.FilteredTextBoxBehavior,
                {
                    "ValidChars": "1234567890.",
                    "id": cellHour_exID
                },
                null, null, $get(cellHour_exPlant));
            });

            // Price
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(7);
            cell6.setAttribute("style", "width:50px; padding-right: 5px;text-align:right;");
            var C6_element2 = document.createElement("input");
            C6_element2.type = "text";
            C6_element2.setAttribute("style", "width:95%; text-align:right;");
            C6_element2.setAttribute("class", "priceChild");
            C6_element2.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_txtPrice" + New_RowNo);
            var blur = "OrderPriceChange('txtPrice" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_');";
            //blur += "onRowDoubleClick_Add_Row('txtPrice" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "');";
            C6_element2.setAttribute("onblur", blur);
            C6_element2.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$txtPrice" + New_RowNo);
            cell6.appendChild(C6_element2);

            var C6_exID = "MainContent_FilteredTextBoxExtender_txtPrice" + New_RowNo;
            var C6_exPlant = "MainContent_txtPrice" + New_RowNo;
            Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                $create(Sys.Extended.UI.FilteredTextBoxBehavior,
                {
                    "ValidChars": "1234567890.-",
                    "id": C6_exID
                },
                null, null, $get(C6_exPlant));
            });

            // Cost
            var cellCost = row.insertCell(8);
            cellCost.setAttribute("style", "width:50px;padding-right:5px;");
            var cellCost_element1 = document.createElement("span");
            cellCost_element1.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:12px;");
            cellCost_element1.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_lblCost" + New_RowNo);
            cellCost_element1.setAttribute("onmouseover", "telerikDemo.onClientMouseOver(this, '0')");
            cellCost.appendChild(cellCost_element1);

            // Status
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(9);
            cell7.setAttribute("style", "width:75px; ");
            var C7_element1 = document.createElement("span");
            C7_element1.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block;width:75px;text-align:center;");
            C7_element1.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_lblStatus" + New_RowNo);
            cell7.appendChild(C7_element1);

            // Crew
            var cell14 = row.insertCell(10);
            cell14.setAttribute("style", "width:75px; ");
            var C14_element1 = document.createElement("span");
            C14_element1.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block;width:75px; text-align:center;");
            C14_element1.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_lblCrew" + New_RowNo);
            cell7.appendChild(C14_element1);



            var cell12 = row.insertCell(11);
            cell12.setAttribute("style", "width:20px;");
            var C12_EID = "MainContent_More" + New_RowNo + "_A_" + New_RowNo;  //"MainContent_Image10_A_10"
            var C12_element2 = document.createElement('a');
            C12_element2.setAttribute("id", C12_EID);
            var linkText = document.createElement('img');
            linkText.setAttribute("src", "Images/more.png");
            C12_element2.appendChild(linkText);
            C12_element2.title = "More";
            C12_element2.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block;height:15px;width:15px;");
            var more_click = "ShowMore('More" + New_RowNo + "_A_" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_','1');"
            C12_element2.setAttribute("onclick", more_click);
            cell12.appendChild(C12_element2);

            var cell13 = row.insertCell(11);
            cell13.setAttribute("style", "width:20px;");

            // Invoice_Check
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(13);
            cell8.setAttribute("style", "width:20px;");
            var C8_element2 = document.createElement("input");
            C8_element2.type = "checkbox";
            C8_element2.setAttribute("style", "width:20px;");
            C8_element2.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_chbInv" + New_RowNo);
            var blur = "OfferChange('chbInv" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "','A_" + New_RowNo + "','A_');";
            C8_element2.setAttribute("onclick", blur);
            C8_element2.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$chbInv" + New_RowNo);
            cell8.appendChild(C8_element2);

            var C8_element2_dummy = document.createElement("input");
            C8_element2_dummy.type = "text";
            C8_element2_dummy.setAttribute("style", "border: 0px solid !important; border-radius: 0px !important; color: #333333; height: 0.1px; opacity: 0.00; padding: 0px !important; width: 0.1px;");
            C8_element2_dummy.setAttribute("id", "MainContent_txtAddRowDummies" + New_RowNo);
            C8_element2_dummy.setAttribute("onblur", "onRowDoubleClick_Add_Row('txtAddRowDummies" + New_RowNo + "','" + New_RowNo + "');");
            C8_element2_dummy.setAttribute("name", "ctl00$MainContent$txtAddRowDummies" + New_RowNo);
            cell8.appendChild(C8_element2_dummy);

            document.getElementById("MainContent_" + id).removeAttribute("onBlur");
            DemoArborGold.JobInformation1.AddRow(New_RowNo.toString());
            // Commented by Shiv on 28-02-2014 
            //var clickButton = document.getElementById(C11_EID);
            // Added by Shiv on 28-02-2014 

            var clickButton = document.getElementById('<%=btnDumies_Add_Roe_Fire.ClientID %>');
            clickButton.click();
        }

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("input[name*='txtAddRowDummies']").live('blur', function ()
            {
                try
                {
                    $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').next().find('input[name*="txtItem"]').focus();
                }
                catch (ex)
                {

                }
            });
        });
.
```

Don't look at the length of the code. In this code, at last you will see `onRowDoubleClick_Add_Row` method. I am calling this method on `blur` of last cell of last row. After this function `new 5 rows` gets added but focus lost. focus should be on `// item number` of newly generated row section.

Comment: what `jquery` version you are using.. ?

Comment: can you post the html structure?

Comment: in my html, i habe simply have one table with id `tblItem` . as you can see in the code, i am getting this table id and inserting rows,attributes etc.

Comment: make sure you are calling focus() function only after you have added those 5 rows.so some code you have used to genrate dynamic controls in jquery.

Comment: exactly. i got that. but where to put that can't figure out..